# Foreground service kotlin using Location and usedLocationProviderClient

Tags: kotlin, google-polyline, foreground-service

I' m really new in Android. I'm doing an application which keeps track of location. How can I save all the location visited every tot interval of time? I realized that since I must be able to save all positions (latitude, longitude) even when the activity is no longer visible, I must use a foreground Service using Location and FusedLocationProviderClient. Then I will use these tuples to build a map of the route taken using Polyline. Tips for doing this Foreground Service? Any kind of suggestion, link, would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the examples of TomTom gave me a view insights in working with location services. https://developer.tomtom.com/maps-sdk-android/android-tutorials-use-cases/search-along-route